# Cancel uncheck in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox

I use checkbox in WPF window. I use some logic in unchecked event of checkbox. And I want to cancel uncheck if need it in the body of this event. How can I do this?

```
    private void chApprove_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        btnAddDepartment.IsEnabled = true;
        brnRemoveDepartment.IsEnabled = true;
    }

    private void chApprove_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (lbSource.Count == 0)
        {
            btnAddDepartment.IsEnabled = false;
            brnRemoveDepartment.IsEnabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Staff already in use! Release it first from dependecies!");
            CheckBox myCheckBox = e.Source as CheckBox;
            myCheckBox.IsChecked = true;


        }
    }
```

Impossible to cancel uncheck !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this easily with an attached behavior (rather than using code behind), you can take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895423/bind-command-to-x-button-of-window-title-bar/2895473#2895473) if you need a sample of how to structure one (it's only a few lines of code).

My spider-sense is telling me this isn't a very good idea though - I can't imagine a way to "justify" rechecking a checkbox that a user has clicked, it just strikes me as very jarring. Can you not either bind the enabled state of the checkbox to a property on your ViewModel or, if you have an ICommand bound to it, use the CanExecute delegate to enable/disable it based on the same logic?

Comment: My checkbox bound to class property with two way databinding (INotifierPropertyChanged also implemented on a class). But manipulating with value of property doesn't help me

Comment: Doesn't really answer my question though - why can't you just enable/disable the checkbox with an additional property on the VM? Then if you are in a state where you aren't "allowed" to uncheck (through whatever logic) the checkbox will be disabled. Seems much cleaner than reverting user input!

Answer (score 5):

```
void CheckBox1_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(ResultOfSomeLogic)
    {    
        CheckBox myCheckBox = e.Source as CheckBox;
        myCheckBox.IsChecked = True; // Check it again
    }
    else
    {
    }
}
```

Also take a look at EventToCommand Binding Behaviour in MVVM Light to take advantage of CanExecute method.

Comment: It not work as expected. Some strange behavior:  uncheked occured and impossible to check it again in UI when I use this code.

Comment: This does not help in situations where flags are critical. If something should already be happening when checked, it wouldn't make sense to initiate that something again just for the sake of keeping a visual element checked.

Answer (score 0):

Bind the IsChecked property of check box. Like

```
IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode = TwoWay}"
```

and in your class define some thing like dis;

```
private bool isChecked;

public bool IsChecked
{
  get
   {
     return this.isChecked;
   }

  set
  {
    this.isChecked = value;
    OnPropertyChanged["IsChecked"];
  }

}
```

and in your event

```
void CheckBox1_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(ResultOfSomeLogic)
    {    
        this.IsChecked = true;
    }
    else
    {
    }
}
```

hope this will work for u..

Good Luck..

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I could not use a solution that allowed unchecking in the first place. If the checked state initiates a critical asynchronous operation, it is not always ideal to uncheck just to check it again: Why allow cancelling this operation if it shouldn't have been allowed to cancel in the first place?

For `MenuItem`s, you can subscribe to the `PreviewMouseDown` event and set `IsCheckable` to **false**; then subscribe to the `Click` event and set `IsCheckable` back to **true**. The reason this works is because `IsCheckable` just determines whether or not to initiate the state change, unlike `IsHitTestEnabled="false"` and `IsEnabled="False"`, which will stop *all* events from firing.

If you try to disable it, no subsequent events will fire making it impossible to restore checkability; by making it uncheckable beforehand, we avoid this mistake. `Click` also happens to occur *after* the state would've been changed so it works out quite nicely.

Unfortunately, `CheckBox` does not have an equivalent `IsCheckable` property; however, the same concepts described above (i.e., `PreviewMouseDown`, `Click` pattern) can produce a similar, if not identical, result.

Answer (score 0):

Well assuming a check box is intended to interact with users instead of programmatic ways, there's a simple way to cancel `Unchecked` events based on some logic when user hits left mouse button or space bar:

```
private void CheckBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    // If it's already checked so next click would uncheck it hence trigger the Unchecked event.
    if ((sender as System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox).IsChecked == true)
    {
        var isConfirmed = false; // Use your confirmation logic here instead.

        // If e.Handled is set to false that will cancel further events such as the Unchecked event.
        e.Handled = isConfirmed;
    }
}

private void CheckBox_PreviewKeyUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // If it's already checked so when user presses space bar it would uncheck it hence trigger the Unchecked event.
    if ((sender as System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox).IsChecked == true)
    {
        if (e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.Space)
        {
            var isConfirmed = false; // Use your confirmation logic here instead.

            // If e.Handled is set to false that will cancel further events such as the Unchecked event.
            e.Handled = isConfirmed;
        }
    }
}
```